# IIS and  Integrated Windows Authentication - login doesn't work for domain.com, works for IP address, localhost, 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, domain, spn

I've installed Windows Server 2003 R2 and IIS role (no Active Directory role).
I've setup a virtual directory named 'test' and under Security tab of the 'test' Virtual Directory I've disabled the Anonymous login and enabled Integrated Windows Authentication. The server is on the local network. What I do is I access the test/ directory on the server using the browser. Here is the log:

```
**IE on Server**
localhost   - works
127.0.0.1   - works, asks for password, 8 second delay
domain.com  - fails, asks for password, after 3 seconds asks for 
             a password again, the username field changes to: domain.com\username
172.28.28.100   - works, asks for password, 8 second delay
```

.

```
**Firefox on Server**
same as above
    domain.com          - the 'Remember the password' tooltip displays for
                          a fraction of a second and then the browser asks
                          for the password again
```

.

```
**IE on other LAN host**
    172.28.28.100   - works, asks for password, 8 sec delay
    domain.com  - works, asks for password, 8 sec delay
**Firefox on other LAN host**
                    - same as above, no delay
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I don't know what is it. I've read about SPNs, but when I use setspn -L localhost, there are no SPNs displayed (I guess it's because the server is not a DC).
Why can't I login  on the server using Windows Integrated Authentication on domain.com?

Comment: Can you capture the authentication conversation with something like wireshark?

Comment: As @trismarck commented below...  Neither of the computers in this question are members of an Active Directory domain.  So SPNs, Kerberos, Negotiate, Integrated Auth, etc. do not apply.

Answer (score 1):

Completely misread the question, so here's try 2.

Assuming:

- the server is an AD 2000+ domain member
- the client is a domain member

When you type "domain.com", IE's going to build a Service Principal Name of http/domain.com and ask a DC to give it a ticket for that.

If domain.com is something real, i.e. your AD domain name, that's not going to fly. At least, I assume not.

Try [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tristank/archive/2006/05/08/spns-r-fn.aspx) for guidance on SPNs. Take the first piece of advice too, and use the 2008 version of SetSPN to do the SPN stuff.

In short, you take the App Pool account (if it's IIS 6, it's Network Service by default, so the computer account 'webserver$') and register an SPN against it:

SETSPN -S http/example.com DOMAIN\WebServer$

In theory, at this point, it all works.

I assume FireFox doesn't do Kerb auth against the server, and that IE takes longer to fail because it's trying to.

Comment: The setspn.exe should probably specify the service for the SPN:  setspn -S HTTP/domain.com ADDomainName\servername

Comment: @TristanK, well, actually both computers aren't part of a domain ;) After further reading about SPNs and service propagation I guess this information is relevant.

Comment: And sorry if my answer dissapointed you ;).

Comment: @RyanFisher good catch!

Comment: @trismarck Yep, that's relevant. It means Kerberos isn't usable, so you're stuck with only NTLM authentication for local user accounts. Once it's authenticated once, it should get faster for subsequent connections, but we're back to traces being required to diagnose the initial slowness.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues to address with this question:

- You cannot authenticate with `domain.com\username` or
  `domain\username` if there is not an Active Directory or NT domain
  called *domain.com* to authenticate to.
- You may have to specifically force the use of a local account by
  using `*IIS Computer Name*\username` as your logon ID to successfully
  authenticate against a local account on the IIS server.
- You probably will want to [set your site NTAuthenticationProviders](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/215383) to disable the *Negotiate*
  authentication process and force IIS to use *NTLM*:
  `cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/__YourWebSite__/root/NTAuthenticationProviders "NTLM"`
- Your simplest, fastest method is going to be using "Basic Auth", but
  there are security issues with that if you aren't protecting your
  logon traffic with SSL.